# Slim Framework routing doesn't work in my code

Tags: php, routes, slim

I'm new to this, I have a problem with following code:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'lib/controller/Root.php';
require_once 'lib/controller/General.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'debug' => true,
 ));

$root_controller = new Root();
$general_controller = new General();

$app->map('/', function() use ($app, $root_controller) {
    $root_controller->index();
})->via('GET', 'POST');

$app->map('/vorstand', function() use ($app, $general_controller) {
    $general_controller->vorstand();
})->via('GET', 'POST');

$app->map('/satzung', function() use ($app, $general_controller) {
    $general_controller->satzung();
})->via('GET', 'POST');

$app->run();
?>
```

I'm using the slim framework and I can't call the routes localhost/vorstand or localhost/satzung everytime I get "Not found" And I have no explanation for that :/ only localhost which means the route "/" works.

Comment: Have you setup htaccess correctly with rewrite rules? You are also using an autoloader as well as requiring the files, this is not needed if you are namespacing correctly. Also you may want to look into singletons within Slim, that way you don't need to `use($root_controller)`

Comment: Do you get an Apache 'not found' or an error rendered by Slim? If the former, then perhaps mod_rewrite is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

For Apache server, two things need to be check.

1.The .htaccess file in the directory (**same directory with your index.php**) contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

2.You also need a directory directive to enable .htaccess files and allow the RewriteEngine directive to be used. This is sometimes done globally in the httpd.conf file, but its generally a good idea to limit the directive to just your virtual host by enclosing it in your VirtualHost configuration block. This is generally setup in your configuration in the form of:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/www.mysite.com/public_html"
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com

    #ErrorLog "logs/mysite.com-error.log"
    #CustomLog "logs/mysite.com-access.log" combined

    <Directory "/path/www.mysite.com/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Add `AllowOverride All` to your DocumentRoot Directory.